# Box2d Collision Impulses

Tags: collision-detection, box2d

I would like to use the impulse of a collision in order to calculate the damage each object in the collision undertakes. So far I have the following:

```
void FMContactListener::PostSolve(b2Contact* contact, const b2ContactImpulse* impulse) {

    // Can be up to 2 for polygon collision
    int count = contact->GetManifold()->pointCount;

    // My two sprites in the collision
    CCSprite *spriteA = (CCSprite*)contact->GetFixtureA()->GetBody()->GetUserData();
    CCSprite *spriteB = (CCSprite*)contact->GetFixtureB()->GetBody()->GetUserData();

    for (int i = 0; i < count; ++i) {
        b2ManifoldPoint point = contact->GetManifold()->points[i];
        // This is the impulse at this point
        float impulse = point.normalImpulse;
    }
}
```

This gives me the impulse at each call to PostSolve for each point in the collision.

I'm no physics student, but doesn't each object have their own impulse as the change in its momentum over the time of the box2d step (say 1/60th of a second)? If I'm getting a single impulse from the collision of two objects, what does this imply?

Comment: I'm no physics guy either, but the momentum of a collision is conserved. So whatever momentum is lost by one object is gained by another object. I forget the exact units on this though, so I can't help with the actual mechanics of it.

Comment: This seems to be the case, so one would simply divide the impulse by the masses of each object and be left with a standardised change in velocity, which could then be used to scale the damages?

Comment: Perhaps, I'm not sure of the units of impulse and if it's consistent like that. You might even consider asking this on the physics stackexchange - many of them are familiar enough with coding to work with you on that aspect of it, considering the primary question here is physics related.